# Global "bare earth" dataset, in GeoTIFF format

Tags: data-request, geospatial

There are many options for downloading elevation data for the Earth (e.g. USGS Earth Explorer), but some of these include vegetation (trees) and structures (buildings).

However, I am looking for a "bare earth" dataset that covers the full globe, downloadable in GeoTIFF format. I would love some suggestions, if anyone is aware of a specific dataset that provides this, or something similar.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you looking for elevation and climate data? Something like topographical data? Do you have a sample of the type of data you seek?

Comment: My apologies. I'm looking for elevation data.  For instance, [USGS](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) has SRTM-1 data.  But this is first-reflection, so it includes reflection from treetops and buildings.  I'm looking for a similar DEM/DTM dataset w/o the trees or building reflections -- only the elevation data.

Answer (score 1):

From what I found from a cursory browsing through the [topographic dataset](http://topotools.cr.usgs.gov/) description of the USGS world, you probably want to use the [Global Multi-resolution Terrain Elevation Data 2010](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/GMTED2010) (GMTED2010), with its 34 page [technical documentation](http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2011/1073/pdf/of2011-1073.pdf), mainly comparing it to the older GTOPO30 dataset. Deviations due to vegetation are discussed (p. 12):

> A raster-based comparison was conducted between
>   GMTED2010 and GTOPO30. The calculated minimum, maxi-
>   mum, mean difference, and standard deviation for the 30-arc-
>   second systematic subsample and mean products compared to
>   GTOPO30 are presented in table 5. The **mean difference** for
>   both GMTED2010 30-arc-second products indicates about
>   a **4.3-meter bias compared to GTOPO30**. One likely reason
>   for the **positive bias** is that the elevation of SRTM areas with
>   foliage represents **vegetation canopy elevations**.

However, the only way to download the dataset seems to be over the clunky [EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) interface, which even requires creating a user account.